# how to add manytomany fields to filter search in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer, django-filter

I have written a search API for my website in django rest framework.
It's an API in which you can set some parameters in the url and get a search result. what I need is to be able to search by genre. What it means is I need the API to be able to do a search like `/api/search/?search=1&search_fields=filmGenre`.  but write now if I send a request to this url I get a FieldKey error with the following message: `Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains`

here is my code:

```
# models.py
class Film(models.Model):
    filmID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    typeOf = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(3), MinValueValidator(1),])
    rating = models.FloatField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10), MinValueValidator(0),])
    releaseDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    
    filmGenre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)


class Genre(models.Model):
    genreID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nameOf = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

```
# serializers.py
class FilmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class GenreFilmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Genre
            fields = ('nameOf', 'genreID',)
            read_only_fields = ('nameOf', 'genreID',)

    class CelebrityFilmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Celebrity
            fields = ('nameOf', 'celebID',)
            read_only_fields = ('nameOf', 'celebID',)
        
    filmGenre = GenreFilmSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    filmActor = CelebrityFilmSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    filmDirector = CelebrityFilmSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Film
        fields = [
            "filmID", "title", "price", "duration", "typeOf", "numberOfFilminoRatings",
            "filminoRating", "rating", "releaseDate", "detailsEn", "salePercentage",
            "saleExpiration", "posterURL", "posterDirectory", 'filmGenre', 'filmActor', 'filmDirector'
        ]
```

```
# views.py
'''Override get_search_fields method of SearchFilter'''
class DynamicSearch(filters.SearchFilter,):
    def get_search_fields(self,view, request):
        return request.GET.getlist('search_fields',[])

'''Override page_size_query_param attribute of PageNumberPagination'''
class CustomizePagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size_query_param = 'limit'


"""Pagination Handler"""
class PaginationHanlerMixin(object):
    @property
    def paginator(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_paginator'):
            if self.pagination_class is  None:
                 self._paginator =None
            else :
                self._paginator = self.pagination_class()
        else :
            pass

        return self._paginator

    def  paginate_queryset(self,queryset):
        if self.paginator is None:
            return None
        
        return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)

    def get_paginated_response(self,data):
        if self.paginator is None:
            raise "Paginator is None"
        return self.paginator.get_paginated_response(data)



class SearchFilm(APIView,PaginationHanlerMixin):
    authentication_classes = ()
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def __init__(self,):
        APIView.__init__(self)
        self.search_class=DynamicSearch
        self.pagination_class=CustomizePagination

    def filter_queryset(self,queryset):
      filterd_queryset=self.search_class().filter_queryset(self.request,queryset,self)
      return filterd_queryset

    def order_list(self,queryset,param):
        field=param.split('_')[0]
        sorting=param.split('_')[1]
        if sorting=='asc':
            return queryset.order_by(field)
        elif sorting=='desc':
            return queryset.order_by(field).reverse()
        

    def get(self, request):
        films= Film.objects.all()
        filtered_queryset=self.filter_queryset(films)
        order_field=request.query_params.get('order_by',None)
        if order_field is not None:
            filtered_queryset=self.order_list(filtered_queryset,order_field) 

        #Get appropriate results for each page
        results=self.paginate_queryset(filtered_queryset)
        if(results is not None):
            serializer=FilmSerializer(results,many=True)
            serializer=self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        else :
            serializer=FilmSerializer(filtered_queryset,many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```